# How to get the number of hours between start and end time when start time greater than endtime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I get the number of hours between

> start time = '23:00:00.0000000'

and

> end time = '07:00:00.0000000'

in SQL SERVER?
I tried using `select DATEDIFF(hour, '23:00:00.0000000','07:00:00.0000000')` but it returns negative hours **-16**.

I want the result to be **8** hours.

Comment: How do you know that the results are 8 hours and not -16 if you don't have the date?

Comment: Sorry I edited my question. I am trying to get the number of hours using start time and end time without date.

Comment: You missed the point.  So how do we know it's just one day and not 2, 3, or 4?  Is the interval inclusive of a 24 hour time period always?  if so you need to check (case) to see if start time > end time.  If it is then you'd need to take 24-start time + end time. otherwise just take end time minus start time.

Comment: Yes the interval is by default 24 hour always.

Comment: Can you please help me with the case statement.

Comment: @newbee You have 2 different answers that give you the result that you want, did you try any of them?

Comment: Yes I did try Lamak they worked! Thanks much !

Comment: @newbee if Lamak's answer worked you should probably accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way then:

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR,'23:00:00','07:00:00') < 0 
                THEN 24 + DATEDIFF(HOUR,'23:00:00','07:00:00')
            ELSE DATEDIFF(HOUR,'23:00:00','07:00:00')
        END
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious issues about not really knowing how many hours as posted above you could kludge this together. Keep in mind that this will always assume less than 24 hours.

```
select DATEDIFF(hour, @StartTime, case when @EndTime < @StartTime then DATEADD(Day, 1, cast(@EndTime as datetime)) else @EndTime end)
```

Comment: Not sure why this is getting a downvote, it's a valid way of doing it

Comment: why not get the absolute value?